# Issue with hover over image as link

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reach the effect where once you hover over image it will change color and once you click on it , it will redirect you to requested page ,so I use it also as a a href. I tried to do css img:hover but it didn't work. My images are png . I am using bootstrap for the website to be responsive.

My HTML:

```
    @extends ('master') 

    @section('content') 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">Myhero Shop</h1> <br><br>
        </div> 
    </div>  
    <div class="row"> 

        @if ($categories)
        @foreach($categories as $category) 
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center"> 
            <h3 >{{ $category['title'] }} </h3>   
            <p class><a href="{{ url('shop/'. $category['url']) }}" class="categorieimg"><img width="250" src="{{ asset('images/' . $category['image']) }}"></a></p>  
            <p>{!! $category['article']!!}</p>  

        </div> 
        @endforeach 
        @else 
        <div class="col-md-12"> <br><br>
            <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px"><b>No categories found...</b></p>
            <div 
                @endif
        </div>
        @endsection   

My css: 

.categorieimg:hover{
    background-color: #080808;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly ! Is there a way to make the image a bit larger when the hover over it?

Comment: @ValerieKurt just add a height/width to the css `img:hover`.

Comment: @ValerieKurt Yes, it is possible to increase the image size or zoom it on hover. But in this case the images should be of a fixed size. I am not sure whether it fits for you

Comment: @AlexanderElgin oh yes I see now its not stable :-(  No other ideas?

Comment: @ValerieKurt I can submit a solution with zoom but it is much more complicated. Can you create a new question for that?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin sure ! Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693827/making-image-larger-on-hover